# Translate list value in aura attribute?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I've got an array in an aura attribute that I wish to use custom labels for:

```
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[{'label': 'Phone', 'value': 'option1'},
                                                    {'label': 'Email', 'value': 'option2'},]"/>
```

Simply replacing the value in 'label' with my custom value like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[{'label': '{!$Label.c.Phone}', 'value': 'option1'},
                                                    {'label': '{!$Label.c.Email', 'value': 'option2'},]"/>
```

Throws an error:

`Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}`

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: are you good with using a server side controller?

Comment: Uhm well, I guess.. I have a few server controllers, just for simpler queries though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you try this?

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
     var defaultOptions = "[{label:$A.get("$Label.c.Phone"),value: 
     'option1' },
     {label: $A.get("$Label.c.Email"), value: 'option2'}]";

    component.set("v. options",defaultOptions);
}
})
```

Call `doInit` method on component load.
if not you give a try with string concatenate in same. I did once, you need to give a try.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure how I can put these in the "default" slot in the attribute though

Comment: The `doInit` will load the default values whenever the component gets initialized. All you need to do is call this method on component init like below.
'<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>'

Comment: Oh, didn't mean that, I know init loads automatically, but I was just wondering if I needed to pass that value to `default= ...`, apparently I didn't, it works!

Thanks for your help!